# Differences between `copy constructor` and `move constructor`.Could anybody make it clear by giving some simple examples

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics

As the subject, I understand `copy constructor` and I am confused after studying `move constructor`.

As the code below, i think `copy constructor` is used to copy the temporary object returned from `fun123()` to obj1, but it uses `move constructor` indeed.

I am a novice in C++.I had been confused for a long time.I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

class ABC  
{  
public:   
    const char *a;  
    ABC()  
     { cout<<"Constructor"<<endl; }  
    ABC(const char *ptr)  
     { cout<<"Constructor"<<endl; }  
    ABC(ABC  &obj)  
     { cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;}  
    //ABC(ABC&& obj)  
    //{ cout<<"Move constructor"<<endl; }  
    ~ABC()  
    { cout<<"Destructor"<<endl; }  
};

ABC fun123()  
{ ABC obj; return obj; }  


int main()  
{   
    ABC obj1=fun123();//NRVO   
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: the key to understand what is going on is on the sentence "copy the temporary object"